# Jest/Jasmine: Weird Execution Order Of beforeEach()

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, jestjs

Given the class:

```
export class Foo {
  private static _count = 0;
  id: number;
  constructor() {
    this.id = ++Foo._count; // starts with 1
  }
}
```

And the test suite:

```
describe('Foo Class', () => {
  describe('constructor', () => {
    const fooClassRef = Foo as any; // to pass typechecking
    beforeEach(() => {
      console.log(`start of beforeEach: ${fooClassRef._count}`);
      fooClassRef._count = 0;
      console.log(`end of beforeEach: ${fooClassRef._count}`);
    });
    describe('creating one Foo obj', () => {
      console.log(fooClassRef._count);
      const foo = new Foo();
      it('should have an id of 1', () => {
        expect(foo.id).toBe(1);
      });
    });
    describe('creating two Foo objs', () => {
      console.log(fooClassRef._count);
      const foo1 = new Foo();
      const foo2 = new Foo();
      it('should have ids of 1 and 2', () => {
        expect(foo1.id).toBe(1);
        expect(foo2.id).toBe(2);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

The second test fails:

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 1
    Received: 2

       |       const foo2 = new Foo();
       |       it('should have ids of 1 and 2', () => {
    >  |         expect(foo1.id).toBe(1);
       |                         ^
       |         expect(foo2.id).toBe(2);
       |       });
       |     });
```

The resulting log is:

```
0
1
start of beforeEach(): 3
end of beforeEach(): 0
start of beforeEach(): 0
end of beforeEach(): 0
```

Seems like the `beforeEach` code isn't actually running until all the tests have already finished.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[This answer is relevant for both Jest and Jasmine!]

The error in the example above is a misunderstanding of how nesting `describe`, `it`, and setup/teardown callbacks work.

(Note that for jest `it` is just an alias for `test`)

Imagine if you added a `beforeEach` before every describe/it call above so that the nesting looks like so:

```
┬─ beforeEach 1
└┬ describe Foo Class
 ├─ beforeEach 2
 └┬ describe constructor
  ├── beforeEach 3
  ├─┬ describe creating one Foo obj
  │ ├─ * - originally constructed a Foo here (but not inside of a beforeEach)
  │ ├─ beforeEach 4A
  │ └─ it should have an id of 1
  └─┬ describe creating two Foo objs
    ├─ * - originally constructed 2 more Foo's here (but not inside of a beforeEach)
    ├─ beforeEach 4B
    └─ it should have ids of 1 and 2
```

The way the order of the `describe`, `beforeEach`, and `it` callbacks will  be run is:

1. Code inside of `describe` callbacks are ultimately run first. You can think of the `describe` code's job to be registering `it`/`test` callbacks and `beforeEach` callbacks (as well as `beforeAll` `afterAll` and `afterEach` callbacks too!). There really shouldn't be any code inside of your `describe`'s (aside from declaring var's to reference) that isn't nested inside of an `it` or `beforeEach` callback - this is ultimately why your test was originally failing.
2. Jest will register each `it`/`test` callback as a "Test" to be run, and will ensure that all `beforeAll`, `beforeEach`, `afterAll`, and `afterEach` callbacks are run appropriately to their nesting.

Following this methodology given the hypothetical tree (where every layer has a `beforeEach`), this results in the following order:

1. originally constructed a Foo here (but not inside of a beforeEach)
2. originally constructed 2 more Foo's here (but not inside of a beforeEach)
3. beforeEach 1
4. beforeEach 2
5. beforeEach 3
6. beforeEach 4A
7. it should have an id of 1
8. beforeEach 1
9. beforeEach 2
10. beforeEach 3
11. beforeEach 4B
12. it should have ids of 1 and 2

Which explains the original order of the logs.

To better test this, let's instead use the follow test code:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  console.log(1);
  const fooClassRef = Foo as any;
  fooClassRef._count = 0;
});
describe('Foo Class', () => {
  beforeEach(() => console.log(2));
  describe('constructor', () => {
    beforeEach(() => console.log(3));
    describe('creating one Foo obj', () => {
      beforeEach(() => console.log('4A'));
      test('should have an id of 1', () => {
        console.log('A');
        const foo = new Foo();
        expect(foo.id).toBe(1);
      });
    });
    describe('creating two Foo objs', () => {
      let foo1;
      let foo2;
      beforeEach(() => {
        console.log('4B');
        foo1 = new Foo();
        foo2 = new Foo();
      });
      it('should have ids of 1 and 2', () => {
        console.log(`4B'`);
        expect(foo1.id).toBe(1);
        expect(foo2.id).toBe(2);
      });
      it('should originally start with ids of 1 and 2, but they could be changed', () => {
        console.log(`4B''`);
        expect(foo1.id).toBe(1);
        expect(foo2.id).toBe(2);
        foo2.id = 47;
        expect(foo1.id).toBe(1);
        expect(foo2.id).toBe(47);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Note that:

- We moved the resetting of the private static property to a `beforeEach` at the top level of the test suit - since resetting that for every Foo test you could run would probably would a good idea if Foo had other methods or logic to test.
- We added another test to the "creating two Foo objs" `describe`
- We added a `beforeEach` where we create our `foo1` and `foo2` to that `describe` since that is setup that we'll want to do for both of our "creating two Foo objs" tests!

Now, all our tests pass, and the resulting log of this test suite is:

```
1
2
3
4A
1
2
3
4B
4B'
1
2
3
4B
4B''
```

***References***

- https://jestjs.io/docs/en/setup-teardown#scoping
- https://jestjs.io/docs/en/setup-teardown#order-of-execution-of-describe-and-test-blocks
- https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/9sy33o/whats_the_difference_of_jests_describe_and_test/