# How to test a Singleton with Jest ? Comparison made between two syntaxes

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, singleton, jsdom

## Context

I am working on unit tests for a TS project led by Dave Gray. ([YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=61v23Ce5SXA), [GitHub](https://github.com/gitdagray/typescript-course/tree/main/lesson11))
More specificaly, I am testing the HTML display which is managed by the class **ListTemplate**. Because there is only one list into our application, this class is a Singleton.

The singleton [defined](https://github.com/gitdagray/typescript-course/blob/main/lesson11/src/templates/ListTemplate.ts) is slightly different compared to [Refactoring.Guru singleton](https://refactoring.guru/fr/design-patterns/singleton/typescript/example#example-0)

In the project,`static instance: ListTemplate = new ListTemplate()` is used while Refactoring.Guru is using

```
public static getInstance(): ListTemplate {
        if (!ListTemplate .instance) {
            ListTemplate .instance = new ListTemplate ();
        }

        return ListTemplate .instance;
    }
```

## Problem

While the behavior of the application remains the same between theses two syntaxes, unit test is not.
I properly configured the jsdom environment so "document" can be altered as we want.

*Call stack - Syntax Singleton Refactoring Guru*

```
"-- FullList constructor --"
"ListTemplate"
"beforeEach global"
"beforeEach local ListTemplate"
"should display html"
"-- ListTemplate constuctor --"
"<ul id="listItems"></ul>"
"HTMLUListElement {}"
```

*Call stack - Syntax Singleton Dave Gray*

```
"-- FullList constructor --"
"-- ListTemplate constructor --"
""
"null"
"ListTemplate"
"beforeEach global"
"beforeEach local ListTemplate"
"should display html"
TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')

      40 |
      41 |   clear(): void {
    > 42 |     this.ul.innerHTML = "";
         |                      ^
      43 |   }
      44 |
      45 |   debugDocAgain(): void {

      at ListTemplate.clear (src/templates/ListTemplate.ts:42:22)
      at ListTemplate.render (src/templates/ListTemplate.ts:50:10)
      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/templates/ListTemplate.test.ts:513:27)
```

With this syntax, the constructor of ListTemplate runs before the initialization of the dom in "beforeEach global", which is not the case with the syntax of Refactoring Guru. Why ?

## Files

Please find below:

- ListTemplate.ts
- ListTemplate.test.ts

```
import FullList from "../model/FullList";

interface DOMList {
  ul: HTMLUListElement;
  clear(): void;
  render(fullList: FullList): void;
}

export default class ListTemplate implements DOMList {
  ul: HTMLUListElement;

  // Syntax 1 - Singleton - Dave Gray
  static instance: ListTemplate = new ListTemplate();

  // Syntax 2 - Singleton - Refactoring Guru
  // private static instance: ListTemplate;

  private constructor() {
    console.log("-- ListTemplate constructor --");
    // console.log(document);
    console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
    // console.log(document.body.outerHTML);
    this.ul = document.getElementById("listItems") as HTMLUListElement;
    console.log(this.ul);
  }

  // Syntax 2 - Singleton - Refactoring Guru
  // public static getInstance(): ListTemplate {
  //   if (!ListTemplate.instance) {
  //     ListTemplate.instance = new ListTemplate();
  //   }

  //   return ListTemplate.instance;
  // }

  clear(): void {
    this.ul.innerHTML = "";
  }

  render(fullList: FullList): void {
    this.clear();

    fullList.list.forEach((item) => {
      const li = document.createElement("li") as HTMLLIElement;
      li.className = "item";

      //   Checkbox
      const check = document.createElement("input") as HTMLInputElement;
      check.type = "checkbox";
      check.id = item.id;
      check.tabIndex = 0;
      check.checked = item.checked;
      li.append(check);

      check.addEventListener("change", () => {
        item.checked = !item.checked;
        fullList.save();
      });

      //   Label
      const label = document.createElement("label") as HTMLLabelElement;
      label.htmlFor = item.id;
      label.textContent = item.item;
      li.append(label);

      //   Button
      const button = document.createElement("button") as HTMLButtonElement;
      button.className = "button";
      button.textContent = "X";
      li.append(button);

      button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        fullList.removeItem(item.id);
        this.render(fullList);
      });

      this.ul.append(li);
    });
  }
}
```

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */

import FullList from "../../src/model/FullList";
import ListItem from "../../src/model/ListItem";
import ListTemplate from "../../src/templates/ListTemplate";
import { getAllByRole, getByText, waitFor } from "@testing-library/dom";

beforeEach(() => {
  console.log("beforeEach global");

  document.body.innerHTML = `<ul id="listItems"></ul>`;
});

describe("ListTemplate", () => {
  console.log("ListTemplate");
  beforeEach(() => {
    console.log("beforeEach local ListTemplate");
    // Doesn't change anything
    // document.body.innerHTML = `<ul id="listItems"></ul>`;
  });
  test("should display html", async () => {
    console.log("should display html");

    // Create items
    const item1 = new ListItem("1", "item1", true);
    const item2 = new ListItem("2", "item2", true);

    // Mocking the getter list of FullList to return mocked data
    jest
      .spyOn(FullList.prototype, "list", "get")
      .mockReturnValue([item1, item2]);

    // Syntax 1 - Singleton - Dave Gray - NOK - Reason ?
    ListTemplate.instance.render(FullList.instance);

    // Syntax 2 - Singleton - Refactoring Guru - OK
    // const singletonInstance = ListTemplate.getInstance();
    // singletonInstance.render(FullList.instance);

    let ulElement: HTMLElement = document.getElementById(
      "listItems"
    ) as HTMLElement;

    expect(ulElement).toBeInTheDocument();

    await waitFor(() => {
      // Li
      const li = getAllByRole(ulElement, "listitem");
      // console.log(li);
      expect(li).toHaveLength(2);

      // Checkbox
      const checkbox = getAllByRole(ulElement, "checkbox");
      // console.log(checkbox);
      expect(checkbox).toHaveLength(2);
      checkbox.forEach((item) => {
        expect(item).toBeChecked();
      });

      // Labels
      expect(getByText(ulElement, "item1")).toBeInTheDocument();
      expect(getByText(ulElement, "item2")).toBeInTheDocument();

      // Buttons
      const buttons = getAllByRole(ulElement, "button");
      // console.log(buttons);
      expect(buttons).toHaveLength(2);
    });
  });
});
```

## Configuration

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.9",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.23.3",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^9.3.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "jsdom": "^24.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^5.1.4"
  }
```

I thought this was related to the [Setup and Teardown of Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/setup-teardown). However, with another [related subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54166833/jest-jasmine-weird-execution-order-of-beforeeach/54166834#54166834), after some tests, position of beforeEach doesn't change anything.

## Expectations

The test should run without problem regardless of the syntax used.

I hope I'm clear on the context, the problem and the expectations. If not, I would be happy to edit the message and give you more information.

Thanks in advance for your time and your expertise on the subject.